# helm template is not using values.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I can't seem to figure out whey my nginx template is not using the values file when I pass it with the `helm template --debug nginx charts/transport-latency -f charts/transport-latency/values.yaml > .ignore/nginx-out.yaml` command.

Output using `--debug`

```
install.go:178: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:195: [debug] CHART PATH: /Users/<userName>/src/Repos/helm_charts/charts/transport-latency
```

Here is the structure of the chart:

```
charts/transport-latency
├── Chart.lock
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
│   └── nginx-13.1.0.tgz
├── templates
└── values.yaml
```

And when I run the above mentioned command I just get the default chart without any modification that should be included in the `values.yaml` file.

Here is what my `values.yaml` file looks like:

```yaml
namespaceOverride: airflow
replicaCount: 2
service:
  type: ClusterIP
```

If it helps here is my `Chart.yaml` contents:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: transport-latency
type: application
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
- name: nginx
  version: 13.1.0
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referencing a dependent chart (in your case, the `nginx` chart), then you must nest values for that subchart in its own block with the name of the dependency.

So, since you named the dependency `nginx` as per your `chart.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: transport-latency
type: application
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
- name: nginx
  version: 13.1.0
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

You must therefore nest the values for that chart in a block labelled `nginx`

`values.yaml`

```yaml
nginx:
  namespaceOverride: airflow
  replicaCount: 2
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
```

Using your values.yaml as it is:

```
namespaceOverride: airflow
replicaCount: 2
service:
  type: ClusterIP
```

Would only provide those to your "root" chart -- which is empty.