# Helm ingress controller does not added paths

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

For a first helm kubernetes deployment with minikube I am trying to set up a Ingress controller. The steps I did.

```
Helm create ingress
```

Remove all files from templates folder and clear content of values.yaml and start with a fresh chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v2
name: ingress
description: A Helm chart for Ingress Controller
type: application
version: 1.1.0
appVersion: 1.17.0
keywords:
  - ingress
  - nginx
  - api-gateway
home: https://github.com/harry
maintainers:
  - name: Harry
    url: https://github.com/harry
dependencies:
  - name: nginx-ingress
    version: 0.15.1
    repository: https://helm.nginx.com/stable
```

Next a command that creates the tgz file

```
helm dependency update
```

followed by a ingress.yaml in /templates

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.ingress.name }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {{ .Values.ingress.annotations.class }}
spec:
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .backend.serviceName }}
                port:
                  number: {{ .backend.servicePort }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

And a default values.yaml

```
ingress:
  name: ingress-service
  replicaCount: 1
  annotations: 
    class: nginx
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: 
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: serviceName
            servicePort: 8080
```

Lastly I apply with

```
helm install -f ingress.yaml ingress ./ingress
```

the following ingress.yaml

```
ingress:
  hosts:
    - host: nutrizone.k8s.com
      paths:
        - path: /api/
          backend:
            serviceName: trala-backend
            servicePort: 8080
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: trala-ui
            servicePort: 8080
```

**Results**

```
kubectl exec pod/ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-55b985bcfd-7p7hk -n default -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

where /api is nowhere to be found and

```
location / {
    return 404;
  }
```

After reinstalling several times and updating to a newer version of nginx (which can be seen in the values.yaml - however old syntax should be converted correctly) I am a bit lost

**After first suggestion to update values.yaml**

I changed the block in values.yaml and parent ingress.yaml to nginx-ingress and updated the /template/ingress.yaml (i needed indexes to make the name 'nginx-ingress' work)

```
helm delete ingress
helm install -f ingress.yaml ingress ./ingress
```

Sadly no difference.

**Update 2 add github project**
https://github.com/Chris2301/helm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependencies:
  - name: nginx-ingress
    version: 0.15.1
    repository: https://helm.nginx.com/stable
```

You have declared that the dependency is called "nginx-ingress". In order for Helm to pass the chart values to the subchart, you need to put these inside a block named the same as the chart so, in your case, you would have to put your values inside a block named `nginx-ingress`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006380/helm-template-is-not-using-values-yaml-file/73006449#73006449) where the OP had the same problem.

---

**UPDATE AFTER VIEWING CODE**

What you have done is correct. The config file does not update because the ingress controller uses your `ingress` resource to determine how to route your request.

For example:

```
$ kubectl get ingress ingress-service -o yaml | grep "spec:" -A 18
spec:
  rules:
  - host: project.k8s.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: project-backend
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /api/
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

I modified the service linked to the "/" in order to test the functionality.

I installed the bitnami nginx chart to provide a test backend service:

```
helm install nginx bitnami/nginx
```

This created a service called `nginx` in the default namespace (also where I installed your chart)

```
$ kubectl get svc 
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.109.222.226   10.109.222.226   80:30892/TCP,443:30210/TCP   27m
kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>           443/TCP                      38m
nginx                   LoadBalancer   10.97.31.201     10.97.31.201     80:32484/TCP                 25m
```

So now I can use the external IP for the loadbalancer created by your chart (`ingress-nginx-ingress`) and hit that using `curl`. We have to use `Host` here so that the ingress controller knows which rule to match.

```
$ curl 10.109.222.226 -H "Host: project.k8s.com"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the controller returned the nginx content correctly. You can verify this by hitting the nginx service directly also (no need to use the `Host` header this time)

```
$ curl 10.97.31.201
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now if we tried to use the `/api/` endpoint, it'll fail because the backend service (`project-backend`) does not exist:

```
$ curl 10.109.222.226/api/ -H "Host: project.k8s.com"
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.23.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

So to answer your original question, the `/api/` is not in the nginx config because the controller uses the ingress resource to determine routing.

Your chart is performing as expected.

Comment: I updated the answer with your suggestions, maybe I still do something wrong? Ty for your fast reply though!

Comment: It may be easier if you are able to share your attempt via a git repo so others can try to reproduce your problem

Comment: Updated! Hope it helps

Comment: Have updated answer

Comment: Ah! thanks alot. Looking in the actual service was also not an option I had thought of, so thanks for pointing that out. Probably very helpful in the future.