# Helm --set on subchart values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using the concept of umbrella charts and am trying to overwrite the values of one of the subchart within the annotations using --set. I need to --set because I created a helm library and trying to build a _deploy.tpl template with static annotation section is not possible. So I used {{- toYaml .template.metadata.annotations | nindent 8 }} to just pull everything under the annotation section.

Say I have a subchart in webapp/charts/app1 and I am wanting to change a the annotation value from app1. How would I go about changing something small like values like
.Values.deployment.spec.replicas

I tried

helm install ./webapp --set app1."deployment.spec.replicas"=4 --dry-run

That didn't work and tried without quotes, I am sure its something simple I am not doing but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify the subchart name in a similar way to described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006380/helm-template-is-not-using-values-yaml-file/73006449#73006449)